# Can moderators see who upvoted or downvoted a question?

Tags: discussion

For Stack Exchange in general—I’d assume that the answer to this question applies for every Stack Exchange—can a “diamond” (moderator) identify who upvoted or downvoted a question? For example, sometimes people will downvote a question or answer without leaving a comment. Does such a person remain anonymous to the moderators, or is there a way for moderators to determine who left the downvote (for example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this information is not available to diamond moderators – they cannot see any user's individual votes other than their own.  They *do* have tools that show cumulative voting patterns, but these don't show individual votes or their connection with comments.

See the following posts on MSE:

- [Can anybody see my voting history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190842/300411)
- [Could moderators see votes in the past?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218120/300411)

Comment: Thanks! Will delete this as it’s evidently a dup. Actually, since you put in the work, I’ll leave it open and allow a mod to delete if they wish.

Comment: Fair enough.  I don't think it's been asked on this meta site at least, and we do have precedent for keeping material here that is also on MSE.  But generally speaking, MSE has the answer for these types of questions.

Answer (score 5):

No, moderators cannot see who up or down voted any posts or comments. This information is considered private and the voting system is *intentionally* anonymous.

As Nathaniel mentioned we do have access to some aggregate voting patterns in the form "X% of user A's votes were for user B". These are considered private and we don't tell users who is voting for who, but we do use it to make sure there are not abusive patterns going on. Two patterns we look for are sock puppet accounts that exist only to upvote the content of some user or revenge voting where some user is using an inordinate amount of their votes to downvote another user.

These patterns will usually result in corrective action of some kind including revoking the votes and/or suspending the guilty parties for a while. The specifics of this are not shared with the community, it's only noted that they have been handled. In rare cases moderators may use this data to rebut accusations about other users that are unfounded. "User A is downvoting all of my posts, they've done it 10 times this week" can be rebutted if user A doesn't show up at all in the voting patterns between the users. More often than not, the user doing the complaining is actually the problem and needs to buck up, stop obsessing over votes, and actually fix their posts.

There is actually one exception to this. In one very specific set of conditions a moderator handling a flag will see a list of actions that the user who lodged the flag took with the post (whether they commented, whether they edited it, whether they voted, and how they flagged). Think of it like this: if you page a moderator in as if they need to intervene with a post, the moderator handling the flag will see what interventions you took as a community moderator before passing it off with a flag. This helps a little bit in understanding how well you evaluated the post and whether you could have taken more actions but didn't. If you are leaving VLQ flags but *not* downvoting then I might question what you expect to have happen next (if it merits a VLQ flag it probably merits a downvote). On the other hand if you NAA flag and downvote then I might review whether the post has more problems than just NAA (NAA could be decent posts not meriting a vote and just be missguided about where they were posted or they could be both NAA and some other offense like personal insults). If you flag something you down voted, but then edit, then then up voted I might check the edit history and consider whether the flag is now obsolete or if there was something there a moderator should still contact the user about.

Note that this only applies to post flags. Flagging comments will not reveal anything about your voting to moderators. In fact comment flags are not even attributed to a flagger, they are shown to moderators anonymously. This is useful to avoid possible bias on "not constructive" flags on comments. We can't fall into the trap of thinking "oh this user just doesn't have thick enough skin to take criticism" because we can't see whether the flagger is somebody involved in the comment thread or a third party reading it and seeing something inappropriate.